# Ошибка C2664 в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Ребят, я совсем недавно начал интересоваться C++, поэтому не могу найти решение для этого.
Если можете, распишите подробно, в чем проблема.

Код взят из Github, причем работал он у всех прекрасно, кроме, конечно же, меня.

Ошибка  C2664   "bool mProcess::Process(char *)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "const char [9]" в "char *"

```
while(Memory.Process("csgo.exe")); //ошибка С2664 тут
    std::cout<<"Found csgo.exe\n";
    ClientMemoryAddress = Memory.Module("client_panorama.dll"); //тут
    ServerMemoryAddress = Memory.Module("server.dll"); /тут
    EngineMemoryAddress = Memory.Module("engine.dll"); /и тут
```

Comment: Текст ошибки дословно добавьте. Думаете их кто-то по номерам помнит? :)

Comment: Это ошибка несоответствия типов аргументов в функции.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2664?view=vs-2019

Comment: Вы используете новейшую версию компилятора, а код был написан под предыдущую версию C++. Можно попробовать в настройках включить более раннюю версию: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55904811/5045688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если эта функция не пишет в передаваемую ей строку (а просто криво объявлена), то можно просто взять и скастить:

```
while(Memory.Process((char*)"csgo.exe"));
```

Если же пишет, то надо для начала знать размер буфера и иметь rw-память такого размера. Простейший вариант:

```
char cmd[256] = "csgo.exe";
while(Memory.Process(cmd));
```

Кстати, конкретно `while` можно заменить на `for`:

```
for (char cmd[256] = "csgo.exe"; Memory.Process(cmd); );
```

PS: И меня смущает `;` после цикла - она там точно к месту?

Comment: **;** Стоит там изначально, мною ничего не правилось. Меня удивляет, что код, выставленный на GitHub, работает у всех, но не у меня, что мешает мне построить приложение. https://github.com/gameAutomationMNNIT/Counter-Strike-Global-Offensive-Aimbot/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: Просто нужно внимательно прочитать комментарий в Readme. "Turn off Conformance mode under C/C++ in your project properties." и все бы компилилось.

Comment: @ЯрославГромов, старые версии студии такое компилировали, не уверен, когда именно поправили.

Comment: @KoVadim, а оно что, отключаемое? В смысле, в VS.

Comment: даже в 2019 студии. сюрприз:) студия (как и весь майкрософт), очень трепетно относятся к всяким хакам совместимости и часто их можно включить назад. даже такое странное.

Comment: @KoVadim, а не хочешь ответ про эту опцию написать?

Comment: думаю, не нужно учить начинающих плохим знаниям. Пусть лучше пишут нормальный код с самого начала. А кому нужно - он увидит.